# Argument Mismatch when using the collect Stream method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The following code:

```
names = Arrays.asList("A","B","C").stream();
List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(() -> new ArrayList<String>(),List::add,List::add);
System.out.println("Individual Strings put into a list: " + namesAsList);
```

generates the following error during compilation:

> List namesAsList = names.collect(() -> new
>   ArrayList(),List::add,List::add);
>                                                   ^ (argument mismatch; invalid method reference incompatible types: ArrayList cannot
>   be converted to int) where R,T are type-variables: R extends Object
>   declared in method collect(Supplier,BiConsumer,BiConsumer) T extends Object declared in interface Stream 1
>   error

When I amend the code to remove the generic the code compiles with an unchecked expression warning:

```
Stream<String> names = Arrays.asList("A","B","C").stream();
List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(() -> new ArrayList(),List::add,List::add);
System.out.println("Individual Strings put into a list: " + namesAsList);
```

Why would I be receiving this error? I do not expect the problem to be relating to an int.

If the answer could include the way of figuring out the issue, this will be appreciated, so I can learn how to solve these problems myself.

Comment: Just a side note, you can use `Stream.of("A","B","C")` for creating a three element stream ad hoc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am practicing for the Java 8 exam, so I use different ways to create a stream object in my practice code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method reference passed for `combiner` does not really fit.
Try:

```
List<String> namesAsList = names
  .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);
```

You passed the `List::add` and compiler is doing its best to try to interpret it as a combiner instance of `BiConsumer` type. Hence, the weird argument mismatch error.

---

Also, I assume you are implementing this only for research purposes. If you want to collect a `Stream` to a `List`, you can simply use:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to collect you `Stream` to `ArrayList` specifically, you can go for:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Why not to simply collect using `Collectors.toList()`?

Comment: @xenteros I assume that the OP is trying to learn how to implement his own collectors. The question was about the compilation problem and not about deriving a list from a stream

Comment: You still can use `List::add` and `List::addAll`, then, the statement still fits into a single line  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the `combiner`, specifically: `List::add` should really be `List::addAll`.

Or more readable like this:

```
List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(
            () -> new ArrayList<>(), 
            List::add, 
            List::addAll);
```

You can re-write that with lambda expression when you are un-sure btw:

```
List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(
            () -> new ArrayList<>(),
            List::add,
            (List<String> left, List<String> right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
            });
```

Notice that there are other problems as-well, like `() -> new ArrayList<String>()`, the type will be inferred by the compiler here, so no need for a `<String>`, like this: `() -> new ArrayList<>()`. Also this can be transformed to a method reference too: `ArrayList::new`, so ultimately it would be even simpler:

```
 List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(
            ArrayList::new,
            List::add,
            List::addAll);
```

This btw is the same thing that `Collectors.toList` does internally, so even further this can be simplified to:

```
List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The only problem is that the specification is free to change that (to return any *other*  `List` besides `ArrayList`), so it could be written:

```
 List<String> namesAsList = names.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: ArrayList::new if using method refrences

Comment: @LazerBanana both options are fine

Comment: @pivovarit they are but not consistent ;)

Comment: @lazerbanana can't argue with that :) using List:: is shorter, though

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It's clearer now. It would be easier to use Collectors.toList(), but I am preparing for the Java certification, so I need to know all the ways :)